# managing streams in period of time with delayedDebounce job-Queue _ nodejs

Tags: node.js

suppose we have a streaming mechanism that clients send some data in a period of time.
we have an array .we push the client data to this array. like this :

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
let list = []
myEmitter.on("data",(data)=>{
    list.push(data.x)

})
```

and for emitting data:

```
myEmitter.emit("data", {x:"some data"})
```

nothing fancy here so far.

we need to have some sort of function that triggers when first-time data arrives in our consumer. we want to do some action to our array and clear it in 30 seconds after the first call. which means the size of the array does not matter and **we don't want to check our array every 30 seconds** (interval way).

conditions :

1. every client has his/her own list(stored in redis)
2. clients streaming time and number of events are not clear to us.

I know one way is writing a simple if statement for checking data exists in our array but this solves only existing data, not the time itself.

Comment: When you first receive data for a specific client, use a `setTimeout(fn, 30 * 1000)` so you can clear it in 30 seconds.  When subsequent data arrives and there's already a timer for that client, either clear the original timer and set a new one or just let the original timer control things.  If there's no timer, then set a new one.  You will need client-specific storage to save the timer handle which could be a session or an appropriate closure.  When the timer fires, clear it's timer handle so you know on the next data operation to set a new timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inspired with [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) 's comment. I finally implement this with [Bee-Qeue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue)
:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
const Queue = require('bee-queue');
const queue = new Queue('test', {
    prefix: 'bq',
    stallInterval: 5000,
    nearTermWindow: 1200000,
    delayedDebounce: 1000,
    redis: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 6379,
      db: 0,
      options: {},
    },
    isWorker: true,
    getEvents: true,
    sendEvents: true,
    storeJobs: true,
    ensureScripts: true,
    activateDelayedJobs: true,
    delayedDebounce:10000,
    removeOnSuccess: true,
    removeOnFailure: false,
    redisScanCount: 100,
  });
let list = []
myEmitter.on("data",(data)=>{
    
    list.push(data.x)
    var time = new Date();
    time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 30);
    const job = queue.createJob({x: data.x}).setId(`${data.id}`)
    .delayUntil(time)
    .save();

})
queue.process(function (job, done) {
    console.log(`Processing job ${job.data.x}`);
    console.log(list)
    list = []
    return done(null, job.id);
  });
let x = 0


setInterval(function(){
    myEmitter.emit("data", {x:x, id:10})
    x = x+1
}, 1000);
```